# How to deploy Gitbucket to Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, gitbucket

I am getting an error when I try to deploy an unmodified version of the latest [Gitbucket](https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket) source to heroku.

> ```
>   [info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.3. Compiling...
>   [info]   Compilation completed in 36.561 s
>   [success] Total time: 142 s, completed Jan 1, 2014 2:04:32 PM
>   [error] Not a valid command: stage (similar: last-grep, set, last)
>   [error] Expected '/'
>   [error] Expected ':'
>   [error] Not a valid key: stage (similar: state, target, tags)
>   [error] stage
>   [error]      ^
> ```
>
> !     Failed to build app with sbt
>
> !     Push rejected, failed to compile Scala app
>
> To git@heroku.com:xxxxxx.git
>   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:xxxxxx.git'

Everything builds and runs locally with no issues.
There is a demo app available at http://gitbucket.herokuapp.com/, so I know it is possible. How can I get around this error?

[EDIT] I have added this to plugins.sbt now, but it still fails in the same way:

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.3")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SBT is trying to run `stage` command and it does not know how. That is usually because you are missing one of the SBT plugins that implements this command (it's not a standard command in SBT).

I checked it out and compiled. It passes tests but it does not have `stage` command. I checked SBT plugins (project/plugins.sbt):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.2.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.1")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalatra.sbt" % "scalatra-sbt" % "0.3.0")

addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-twirl" % "0.6.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.timushev.sbt" % "sbt-updates" % "0.1.2")
```

And nothing looks like heroku deployment plugin or similar. How are you deploying it and how are you invoking it?

[EDIT] Given your updates I looked up the plugin: https://github.com/typesafehub/xsbt-start-script-plugin.
I think you added the plugin to the project which is good, but not sufficient. Now you need to configure project settings similar to this:

```
import com.typesafe.startscript.StartScriptPlugin
settings = StartScriptPlugin.startScriptForClassesSettings
```

See the github README for details.

Comment: I ran `heroku create` and now am running `git push heroku master`. I've also added to plugins.sbt now without luck.